# How to use `git grep --not`

Tags: git, grep

I would like to run a `git grep` command for a `<pattern>`, but exclude lines which are over 200 characters.

I have managed to achieve this with the command:

```sh
git grep <pattern> | grep -Ev '.{200}'
```

If possible, I would like to run this as one command (without a pipe).
I thought I would be able to make use of the `git grep` `--not` flag for this, but am running into difficulty.

Here is my attempt:

```sh
git grep -e <pattern> --not -e '.{200}'
```

I have tried different combinations of the above command, but haven't gotten the desired output.

Any pointers on what I should try next would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance for the help.

---

**Solution**:

(thanks to @torek)

```sh
git grep -E -e one --and --not -e '.{200}'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [description of the boolean operators for `git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt---and) reads:

> **--and**
>   **--or**
>   **--not**
>   **( …​ )**
>   Specify how multiple patterns are combined using Boolean expressions. `--or` is the default operator. `--and` has higher precedence than `--or`. `-e` has to be used for all patterns.

You used:

> `git grep -e <pattern> --not -e '.{200}'`

so you did write `-e` for each pattern; but you did not pick one of `--and` or `--or`, so you got the default.  Which one is the default?  (Read the quoted text above.)  If you ask for things that match some pattern *or* are *not* at least 200 characters, will something that's 12 characters long be selected?  It's not at least 200, so yes, it will be selected.  What about something that's both 234 characters *and* matches?   Well, it matches, so yes, it will be selected.  The only things that will be rejected are those that both *don't* match *and* are 200 characters or longer.

Note that `git grep` itself also defaults to basic regular expressions, unless you use a command line option or configure it to use extended or Perl regular expressions.  So you probably want `-E -e <pattern> --and --not -e '.{200}'` here.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: Amazing answer with thorough explanation, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `awk` for this problem.

`awk '/<pattern>/ && length($2) < 200'`