# Negating a regular expression

Tags: regex, git, hook, regex-negation

I have the following RegEx which I use in a pre-push git hook to verify the commit message:
`^[mM].*|^[cCfF].*ABCDE-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*`
The message is supposed to start with m/M OR start with c/C/f/F  AND ABCDE-4+ digits.
I use it with git rev-list like so:
`commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 --grep '^[mM].*|^[cCfF].*ABCDE-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' "$range")`

The rev-list command currently returns a value for commit if the commit message is valid. I would instead like to get the ID(s) of the faulty commits returned. I don't know much about RegEx, so I thougth that there would be a simple way to negate the whole expression.

I tried the negative lookaround and several different ways of escaping some of the characters but nothing really worked.
`(^(?![mM].*))(^(?![fFcC].*ACRNG-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*))` seems to work as intended in the online RegEx tester but I can't make it run correctly in the hook.
The entire hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

# An example hook script to verify what is about to be pushed.  Called by "git
# push" after it has checked the remote status, but before anything has been
# pushed.  If this script exits with a non-zero status nothing will be pushed.
#
# This hook is called with the following parameters:
#
# $1 -- Name of the remote to which the push is being done
# $2 -- URL to which the push is being done
#
# If pushing without using a named remote those arguments will be equal.
#
# Information about the commits which are being pushed is supplied as lines to
# the standard input in the form:
#
#   <local ref> <local oid> <remote ref> <remote oid>
#
# This sample shows how to prevent push of commits where the log message starts
# with "WIP" (work in progress).

remote="$1"
url="$2"
zero=$(git hash-object --stdin </dev/null | tr '[0-9a-f]' '0')

var=$(git rev-list --max-count=100 HEAD)

remoteChanges=true


while read local_ref local_oid remote_ref remote_oid
do
    var_split=$(echo $var | xargs)
    for value in $var_split
    do
        if test "$value" = "$remote_oid"
        then
            remoteChanges=false
        else
            :
        fi
    done
    if "$remoteChanges";
    then
    echo "falsch"
        echo "Es gibt neue Commits im Remote Repository. Bitte zuerst einen Pull durchführen."
        exit 1
    else
        :
    fi
    
    #Commit Message überprüfen
    if test "$local_oid" = "$zero"
    then
        # Handle delete
        :
    else
        if test "$remote_oid" = "$zero"
        then
            # New branch, examine all commits
            range="$local_oid"
        else
            # Update to existing branch, examine new commits
            range="$remote_oid..$local_oid"
        fi

        # Check for WIP commit
        commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 --grep -v '(^(?![mM].*))(^(?![fFcC].*ACRNG-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*))' "$range")   
        if test -n "$commit"
        then
            echo "commit: $commit"  
        else
            echo "commit: $commit"
            echo >&2 "Die Commit-Message enthält keine gültige Jira-Vorgangsnummer der Form ACRNG-0000"
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
done

exit 0
```

Comment: What about the `-v` with the `grep`?

Comment: Fehler beim Übertragen per Push an das Remoterepository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
f1e6fedc9b1484f9db67aa94b4665c48b11886ce..d49042e66dfe2e4719a4705740e8acc7cba57794: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.
Die Commit-Message enthält keine gültige Jira-Vorgangsnummer der Form ACRNG-0000
failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/lfischer-dafo/LiveDemo.git'

Sorry, it's partly in German. I added the whole hook below for context.

Comment: Sorry, looks like it is `--not` in `git` command, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203430/how-to-use-git-grep-not.

Comment: When I use `commit=$(git rev-list -n 1 --grep '^[mM].*\|^[cCfF].*ACRNG-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' --not "$range")`  I basically have the same outcome.

Comment: I think `| grep -P` is more reliable. Git's regex is really awful.